# I am trying to refresh the marker on google map without refreshing the whole page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have written the following code. The values a and b in the code are latitude and longitude values which are periodically updated by python code that is running. But the marker does not seem to refresh for every 3 seconds as expected though the values of a and b change.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tracking</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #map-canvas 
{ 
height: 100%; 
width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script>
    var a;
    var b;


    a=17.429385;b=78.4451901667;



var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
zoom: 16,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(a,b),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

function initialize() {
var map = map;
}

function loadMarker(a,b) {

latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(a,b);
new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
}

$(document).ready(
        function() {
            setInterval(function() {


            a=17.429385;b=78.4451901667;      




            latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(a,b);
                marker=new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
                marker.setMap( map );
                marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( a, b) );
                map.panTo( new google.maps.LatLng( a, b) );
            }, 3000);
        });


initialize();
loadMarker(a,b);        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a space in your jquery script url.

Comment: oops..i missed the hyphen there..I changed the code now..it still doesn't work.

Comment: The code just here is working, it mean the error is when you get your value from python. How do you get them ?

Comment: The python code edits the above html file and rewrites the lines with the coordinates i.e a=17.429385;b=78.4451901667; with new coordinate values periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tracking</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #map {
                height: 100%;
            }
            #map-canvas 
            { 
                height: 100%; 
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        <script>
            var a, b, varInterval, marker = [];

            var markersPlacement = 0;
            var locations = [];
            locations.push(17.429385 + ',' + 78.4451901667);
            locations.push(41.8369 + ',' + 87.6847); //Chicago
            locations.push(36.1215 + ',' + 115.1739); //LA

            var defaultLocation = locations[markersPlacement].split(',');
            var mapIcon = 'http://images.clipartpanda.com/google-location-icon-location-map-512.png';

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                zoom: 5,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(defaultLocation[0]), parseFloat(defaultLocation[1])),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            function deleteMarkers() {
                clearMarkers();
                marker = [];
            }
            function clearMarkers() {
                setMapOnAll(null);
            }

            // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
            function setMapOnAll(map) {
                for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
                    marker[i].setMap(map);
                }
            }

            function addMarker(location) {
                var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    map: map,
                    icon: mapIcon,
                });
                marker.push(mark);
            }


            $(document).ready(
                    function () {
                        varInterval = setInterval(function () {
                            console.log(markersPlacement);
                            console.log(locations.length);
                            if (locations.length >= markersPlacement) {
                                deleteMarkers();

                                //REMOVE THE BELOW AND ADD THE AJAX CODE BELOW HERE.
                                defaultLocation = locations[markersPlacement].split(',');
                                addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(defaultLocation[0]), parseFloat(defaultLocation[1])));
                                markersPlacement++;
                            } else {
                                clearInterval(varInterval);
                            }

                        }, 5000);
                    });


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You now have to make sure that the values of a and b get updated when the setInterval runs.

#### Ajax Code

```
// response would be something like
// {"location":{"lat":41.881832,"lng":-87.623177}}

$.ajax({
   cache: false,
   url: "/path/to.json",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(response) {
       addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(response.location.lat), parseFloat(response.location.lng)));
   }
});
```

Comment: The code still loads only the initial location with values of a and b.But doesn't refresh the marker to the new location after a and b gets updates.

Comment: If I understand correctly. What you are trying to do is to move the marker as the location changes? I have updated the code above. Give it a try and let me know if that works well for you.

Comment: The code above moves the marker to the new positions as expected. But I want to edit the locations in the above code continuously so that the marker keeps moving as the locations gets updated. Can we manage to do that.

Comment: Yeah! You'll have to use ajax within the setInterval function and call the the python file you have to return the new coordinates. Once you have them pass it to the addMarker function and it will delete the old marker and add new one.

Comment: Thank you Mir. Could you help me with the way in which i can do the ajax part for updating the locations periodically. The python file contains only one line which gets updated with new values of coordinates every few seconds. This new coordinates need to be marked on map.

Comment: I have added the Ajax code separately. You can place it in the setInterval method and point the url parameter to your python file. Make sure the response.location.lat points to the correct array values. Then it should work fine.

Comment: Can't we use a text file with the following content {"location":{"lat":41.881832,"lng":-87.623177}} in the ajax method to replace the coordinate values a and b periodically. I am not able to do that.

Comment: If you want to use a text file. You can simply include it in the main file instead of using ajax. How many locations do you have? Is it that you query from db or some API?

Comment: The text file has single line with only one location,that keeps updating every 3 seconds. For every change in the location in the text file the marker in the map should move to the updated location. i.e the coordinates in the above code must get updated to the value that is in the text file periodically. I am doing this using python to read that text file and write the content of that file into the javascript code.

Comment: Then, instead of using text use .json. You will have to change the url path to the json file path. If you do it in .txt format you will have to set json headers.

Comment: Also make sure you do cache false or pass a random string along with the request to ignore caches. I have updated the code above to support that too

Comment: Mir thank you for helping me so far. I am still struck with the text file reading.The problem is the text file is in my local hard drive and the coordinates gets updated in that text file periodically, can i still use ajax and access that text file to update the values in javaScript code.

Comment: To put in simple terms please help me understand how to keep updating the variables a and b in the above code every few seconds in the background and the changes in these variables must be reflected in the map in the browser.

Comment: Your ajax should point to your text file. Ajax will connect the text file, read the lat and lng and then update coordinates on the map.

Comment: My text file has the following data and it gets updated periodically {"location":{"lat":41.881832,"lng":-87.623177}} . So the below code will access that text file and update the javascript variables?                       $.ajax({
   cache: false,
   url: "\path\raw.txt",
   dataType: "text",
   success: function(response) {
       addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(response.location.lat), parseFloat(response.location.lng)));
   }
});

Comment: Yes. It will work. But you have to change the way how the variable handles values. Since you are doing text. Do something like var cooridinates = response.split(','); then do var lat = parseFloat(cooridinates[0]); var lng = parseFloat(cooridinates[1]); In the text files simply store 41.48797,-87.1601305 and that should do the work for you.

Comment: Is it possible to do the above method only with html and javascript, where the marker gets updated periodically when the latitude and longitude values passed to the function changes every few seconds.

Comment: Yes. But how do the values get passed? You can send a pusher event and trigger the update function if you don't want to use ajax.